# First Time Trying to Edit a SharePoint File

Tags: sharepoint-2010, single-sign-on, remote-desktop

This is my first time trying to edit a sharepoint file.  It is used as a list of links in an iframe on a web site on another server.  But this has nothing to do with the problem.  I have been asked to modify the list of links and I just want to get to it and do it.  But however one does this, it does not seem very intuative to me.

Let me tell you the steps I have taken and how things go wrong and maybe I can get some advice.  The sharepoint file is on a server that I log into remotely.  I run the "Sharepoint 2010 Central Administration".  On the page that comes up, I click on "Manage web applications"  under "Application Management".

From there, I see the page I want to edit.  But when I click on the name of the item (which appears in red text) the area is hilighted but nothing happens.  In the ribbon menu at the top of the page there is a drop down entitled "Site Actions" but there is no option there to "edit".  Please advice.

[image: http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/SSO/SSo1_zps60b19ba2.png]

I was given a username and password to "log in" because I was told I need that.  The idea was that maybe I need a special admin account to see the missing menu options to edit a page.  But at first I could not use it to log on to the server where the sharepoint system is.  Then I found that I could try to use it to log onto the "Sharepoint 2010 Central Administration" program.  But this did not work.

Then I tried to see if there was anything I could so from the desktop computer.  I found "Microsoft SharePoint Workspace 2010"

I tried this and it looked promising"
http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/SSO/SSO3_zpse15402e2.jpg

But then eventhough I could see the file name, I could not edit the file:
http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/SSO/SSO4_zpsca7d0f71.jpg

I went back to the server and tried a few other things.  I tried to switch my account in the Central Adminstration to this special account that someone suggested had more privledges but it did not work.  The error said "Error: Access Denied".  I tried putting the web page in the address bar and that just brought up the page without any way of editing it.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Central Administration is not meant for content editting. That is the core of SharePoint with all kind of configuration options. 
You have to create a web application for content editting and create a site collection there. In that site collection you can edit the page, add webparts, etc. In your case you can try a Publishing Portal template for your site collection and add a content editor webpart. In that content editor webpart you can put HTML for your iframe.

Comment: The content is already there.  How do I check it out to edit it?

Comment: Site-actions -> Edit Page for pages, or go to the document library (Site-Actions -> View all site content -> go to library), for documents. However, this is really basic SharePoint. Please consider an online course / introduction or whatever to try to understand the basics of SharePoint.

Comment: If I am not to used Central Administration for content editing, what app or tool should I use?   You say it is under SiteActions, but using what program?  I downloaded the Microsoft SharePoint Workspace and I got this far http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/SSO/workspace_zpsba83780c.jpg and this is the file I want to edit, the "SU Single Sign On" but I do not know how to get there.  I watched the first of the training videos from Microsoft for using SharePointWorkspace and they said to sync with the sharepoing site.  That is part of the problem.  Where do I find the site?

Comment: As said: You have to create a web application for content editting and create a site collection there.  
Again, this is really, really basic SharePoint.